# pandas read_excel converting special charactor

Tags: python, pandas, encoding, special-characters

I am reading data from excel and writing it to CSV file.

```
osht = pd.read_excel(ip_path,header=None,sheet_name=j,encoding='utf-8-sig')
osht.to_csv(file_name,sep=',',index=False,encoding='utf-8-sig')
```

Excel file has some lines which has special characters like :

> 'SOCIÉTÉ' , 'HERMÈS'

Pandas changes such words to :

> 'SOCIÃ©TÃ©' , 'HERMÃŠS'

I tried changing encoding method to 'utf-8', 'utf_16_le' but issue still persisted.

Please suggest whats needs to be done in such case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> 'SOCIÃ©TÃ©' , 'HERMÃŠS'

This suggests the resulting file is not UTF-8 encoded.

Comment: Hi Azmi, while writing data to new csv file I am specifying encoding as 'UTF-8'. will this not make resulting file UTF-8 encoded/compatible ?

Comment: Its got fixed by deleting destination csv file and let python create new file